# mascara para formatear dato de entrada

Tags: html, django

como puedo generar una mascara para formatear un dato de entrada, me explico, estoy trabajando en una aplicación web bastante antigua en django(1.5)y quiero dar formato a un campo de un formulario de registro (en este caso rut chileno de la forma xx.xxx.xxx-x ) de momento no es necesario validar que el rut ingresado sea valido, solo que quede del formato antes mencionado, de antemano gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la idea es que sin importar el numero que ingrese, este quede asì. PD:no tomen en cuenta lo de numero de pasaporte.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes utilizar mask un plugin de jquery, puedes verlo [aquí](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: lo revisaré, gracias !